# How do you reuse a queue from Thread::Queue?

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue

I was provided some guidance on here at one time, with the following snippet:

```
my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
sub worker {
    my ($job, $action) = @_;
    Build($job, $action);
}

for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
  async {
     while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
        worker($job, 'clean');
     }
  };
}

$q->enqueue($_) for @compsCopy;

# When you're done adding to the queue.
$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

What is the best option for reusing `q`? Currently, I'm just making new `q` objects, `q2`, `q3` and doing all of this over again for each `$action` that I want to perform. Is there a better way though? I could potentially pass in an array of "actions" that I would like to perform, and would like to avoid duplicating this code 7 times if possible.

Maybe I don't fully understand what a `Thread::Queue` is..

Comment: Again, just put in the queue whatever information you need to complete the job. If that includes a job type, so be it. You've already been given the code to do that: `->enqueue([ $job_type, @job_params ])`

Comment: Re "Maybe I don't fully understand what a Thread::Queue is, ", It's a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29). Think of it as an array that only supports `push` (enqueue) and `shift` (dequeue). T::Q has the distinguishing feature that clients block on attempts to dequeue if there's nothing to dequeue (unless `end` has been called).

Comment: If I'm placing work into the que with `->enqueue`, what is the for loop for?

Comment: To create the worker threads. `async {...};` is a clean way of writing `thread->create(sub {...});`.

Comment: I guess I also don't understand the `$_` here.. can you help explain? What would be the long-hand of using the `$_`?

Comment: Really? I have to explain what a for loop is? `$_` is aliased to an element of `@compsCopy`, each one in turn. For example, if `@compsCopy` has 5 elements, `$q->enqueue($_)` will be executed 5 times. The first time, `$_` will be aliased to `$compsCopy[0]`; the second, to `$compsCopy[1]`; etc.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's frustrating but I'm really new to perl and had no concept of what `$_` was until today. So does the code above create the threads, but not execute them during the for loop; `enqueue` pushes the parameters I want to pass; `->end` .. I guess kicks off the threads?

Comment: My mistake, I realize now that `->end` doesn't kick of threads (obviously) - but I guess I'm curious how/when they do get kicked off?

Comment: `$_` is just a plain ordinary variable // When they return from the BLOCK that's `async`'s argument (when they return from the sub passed to `create`).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So my only question now is, what's the point in `enqueue`? Is that just to keep track of the threads that were made so that we can join them?

Comment: To give the worker threads something to do. Seriously man, take a second to look at the code. If you didn't enqueue anything, what would dequeue return? And it dequeue didn't return anything, `worker` would never get called.

Comment: I mean, that makes sense completely.. but doesn't `enqueue` get called *after* the loop finishes? Should I be placing my call to `enqueue` before the loop?

Comment: Which loop are you talking about? Are you talking about the loop that creates the threads (`for (1..NUM_WORKERS)`) [yes, but so what], or the loop every thread executes (`while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue()))`) [no, why do you think it is?]?

Comment: I guess I assumed the loop within the thread would have finished - but I just looked up `defined` and saw that I probably misunderstood it's purpose here. My assumption now is that the thread-loop continuously checks the queue, and unless `end` has been called on the que, the returned object will be something other than `undef` - is this correct?

Comment: What returned object? You haven't enqueued anything yet! We've already covered `dequeue` blocks if there's nothing in the queue (unless `end` has been called).

Comment: Ok thanks for all of the help; this is all making more sense now. My only question at this point is how can I access the parameters I `enqueue` with my `$job`? Say if I do: `->enqueue($_, 'clean') for @compsCopy`, how would I access the `clean` parameter when I'm doing `my $job = $q->dequeue()` and then calling the worker?

Comment: 3rd time: `->enqueue([ $job_type, @job_params ])`, or if you prefer `my $job = [ $job_type, @job_params ]; ->enqueue($job)` /// In `worker`, you'd do the inverse. You'd dereference the array ref: `my ($job_type, @job_params) = @$job;`

Comment: Hm, when I do that I get some issues. I'll post a new question about it though. If you want to add an answer to this with a summary of what you've helped with.. that way you can get some rep from the help you've given.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one queue for one direction. If you just would like to some operation paralel, use one queue. If you would like to report back errors and process those error in main or another thread then you use two queue.

for simple use here is for your reference:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue
my %seen: shared;

# Worker thread
my @thrs = threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;#for 5 threads
add_file_to_q('/tmp/');
$q->enqueue('//_DONE_//') for @thrs;
$_->join() for @thrs;

sub add_file_to_q {
  my $dir = shift;
  my @files = `ls -1 $dir/`;chomp(@files);
  #add files to queue
  foreach my $f (@files){
    # Send work to the thread
    $q->enqueue($f);
    print "Pending items: "$q->pending()."\n";
  }
}



sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    while (my $filename = $q->dequeue()) {
      # Do work on $item
      sleep(1) if ! defined $filename;
      return 1 if $filename eq '//_DONE_//';
      next if $seen{$filename};
      print "[id=$ithread]\t$filename\n";
      $seen{$filename} = 1;
      ### add files if it is a directory (check with symlinks, no file with //_DONE_// name!)
      add_file_to_q($filename) if -d $filename;
    }
    return 1;
}
```